# How to automatically enable Recordtypes for Scratch org admin

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

Whenever I create my scratch org I have to manually assign Record Types to the `Standard User` and `System Administrator` profile.

Is there any way to automize that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Robert. Why would you not add a secondary packageDirectory that is not included in the package version build but contains a profile metadata item that maps the record type for the profiles and would be pushed to the scratch org when you do a force:source:push ?